# CSS: z-index of next element to change on hover

Tags: html, css

I really hope that I have worded this correctly. Please feel free to ask for any clarifications needed.

I have a **ul** with **li** float left like so:
[image]

each of those has a link in the top right corner, here is the HTML for those:

```
<li>
    <div class="description">
        <p><strong>Title</strong><br>
        <br />
        This worksheet features diagrams of the different molecule structures found in solids liquids and gases, and descriptions of the different states. Simply label the diagram and draw a line to link the description to the diagram to complete the workshe</p>
    </div>
    <a class="fav_icon" data-id="71933" title="favorite">Fav</a>
</li>
```

That div 'description' has display:none property until the li is hovered over, then it has display block.

The link in the top right (red circle) is the link to fav the article. That has a z-index: 99999 as well as now position absolute top right.

The problem is, if the hovered over div is too long and runs over the div below, the top right link goes over, like so:

[image]

I need the current hovered divs child of **.fav_icon** to be higher than the hover, however, I need the rest to be lower. so it should look like:

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Edit: CSS

Here is the CSS:

```
 .resource-preview {

 .description {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(14, 134, 201, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 99999;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 4px;


  p {
    padding-top: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}

  &:hover {
    .description {
      display:block;
    }
  }


.fav_icon {

  padding: 3px 5px;
  height: 21px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  outline: 3px solid white;
  z-index: 9999;

}
```

Comment: Could you include your CSS too, thanks

Comment: Can you post your full code please? You can do it with JavaScript or maybe you could restructure your DOM and do it with CSS.

Comment: see changes added to main Q

Comment: That's no CSS that you postet

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @CodeiSir apologies, no it is SCSS, however as there are no variables or special cases its perfectly legible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a little sample for you. If you awaiting hover on the li - than it is no big deal - you have to just change the z-index of the current li ;)

https://codepen.io/samuells/pen/gWJyBv?editors=0100

```
li:hover {
 p {
  display: block;
  background-color: firebrick;
  z-index: 11;
 }
 a {
  z-index: 12;
 }
}
```

Comment: So simple I overlooked it. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

Find below an example with the correct z-index settings. Most essential is the -1 for the icon.

```css
.description {
display:none;
font-size:9px;
background-color:white;
margin-top: 35px;
padding: 5px;
}
li:hover .description {
display:block;
z-index:1;
}
li {
float:left;
clear:both;
width: 100px;
height: 150px;
list-style:none;
border: thin solid #000;
border-radius: 8px;
position:relative;
}
.fav_icon {
font-size: 10px;
background-color: red;
border-radius:50%;
width:30px;
height:30px;
position:absolute;
right:1px;
top:1px;
z-index:-1;
)
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="description">
        <p><strong>Title</strong><br>
        <br />
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <a class="fav_icon" data-id="71933" title="favorite"></a>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="description">
        <p><strong>Title 2</strong><br>
        <br />
        This worksheet features diagrams of the different molecule structures found in solids liquids and gases, and descriptions of the different states. Simply label the diagram and draw a line to link the description to the diagram to complete the workshe</p>
    </div>
    <a class="fav_icon" data-id="71933" title="favorite"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the html putting the icon first. Then just giving any positive z-index value to your description would be enough.

```css
div {
  float:left;
  width:30%;
  margin-right:10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;  
}
span {
  position:absolute;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-color:red;
  display:block;
}
p {
  display:none;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#bbb;
  border:1px solid #000;
  z-index:20;
  position:relative;
}
div:hover p {
  display:block;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span></span>
   <h4>title</h4>
   <p class="description">descriptidescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thison as long as this</p>
   
</div>
<div>
    <span></span>
   <h4>title</h4>
   <p class="description">descriptidescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thison as long as this</p>
   
</div>
<div>
    <span></span>
   <h4>title</h4>
   <p class="description">descriptidescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thison as long as this</p>
   
</div>
<div>
    <span></span>
   <h4>title</h4>
   <p class="description">descriptidescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thisdescription as long as thison as long as this</p>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

U can use style for siblings

```
li:hover ~ li .fav_icon
{
   z-index: *as u want*;
}
```